# Confusion with how promise works asynchronously

Tags: javascript, promise

I am new to JS and was learning promises. As you can see the code below:

```
function makeRequest (method, url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject({
          status: this.status,
          statusText: xhr.statusText
        });
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
      reject({
        status: this.status,
        statusText: xhr.statusText
      });
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
}

// Example:

makeRequest('GET', 'http://example.com')
.then(function (datums) {
  console.log(datums);
})
.catch(function (err) {
  console.error('Augh, there was an error!', err.statusText);
});
```

I would like to ask some questions on the work of the above code. So, when we execute the above code, it will right away return promise(since it is not asynchronous) but xhr object will execute via event loop. The question is How exactly asynchrony happens with then(), I mean, after we got data from xhr object thanks to resolve, does the asynchrony happen when the data handled with resolve(xhr.response) is passed to then(). **The second question**, why do we need one more asynchrony in then() since we already got the data from asynchronous xhr we just need to show the data like .then((datums){console.log(datums)})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the code works is it returns a promise. This means that the code inside that promise is only executed when the function is called - and yes, the function *is* asynchronous because it returns a promise. So you need to use `.then` to wait for the promise returned by the function to resolve or reject, and *then* execute the code contained inside the passed callback function(s).

This particular example of code is slightly confusing because usually when dealing with AJAX, XMLHttpRequest and the Fetch API, you wouldn't usually be constructing the promise - you'd just be consuming the promises created by the APIs. Here's a simple example involving the Fetch API:

```
function generatePromise() {
  return fetch("http://example.com");
}

generatePromise().then(res => console.log(res), err => console.log(err));
```

Here, what happens is the Fetch API makes a request to the page we want (`http://example.com`), and returns a pending promise from that function. This promise has been constructed by the Fetch API - in this instance, the developer is the consumer of the promise rather than the producer.

Because `generatePromise` returns a `Promise <pending>`, we need to use `.then` to wait for it to complete. Once it's completed, we pass two functions (you can use this approach, or `.then` and `.catch` with one callback each) - the first is the success function, and will be called if the promise has been `resolve`d. The second is the failure function and will be called if the promise has been `reject`ed.

The `.then` is required to wait for the promise to complete, otherwise we'd be working without the data, which is usually the whole point of the request. You always need these, or `async`/`await`, when dealing with promises (unless some fancy library makes it synchronous for you).

Comment: thank you Jack for your kind comments, I have a question, does the callback of then() execute via event loop asynchronously, if so, WHY? since as you said then() waits for a data and after it gets the data why need to again execute callback which is inside then() asynchronously?

Comment: What do you mean? The callback passed to `.then` is called synchronously unless it's an asynchronous function (using `async` or other methods)

Comment: please can you read comments written by "@Bergi" here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135333/how-promise-works-behind-the-scenes"  he states that callback in .then is called asynchronously

Comment: what do you think Jack about that?